# Is there any way to linnk audio / sound files to buttons in the graphical layout view in eclipse?

Tags: android, audio, media

Wondering if there is any way to link audio files to buttons in graphical view?

Possibly by going into properties of the button and linking it somehow to the sound file in the res > raw folder??

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've been using Eclipse for a long time, and I've never seen such an option.  I would be pretty surprised if it existed.